# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface on WCF Silverlight Service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I'm working through two tutorials to create a super simple WCF web service and Silverlight app.

[Buiding a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197940(v=vs.95).aspx)

[Accessing a Service from Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197937(v=vs.95).aspx)

Everything was going fine. I created my service:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace TestOnline.Web.Data
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [SilverlightFaultBehavior]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class DataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public String TestService()
        {
            return "Service Worked!";
        }
    }
}
```

I added it as a service reference, then tried to create an instance but I'm getting the error "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface" on the line "proxy = new DataService();"

I pretty much followed the steps of the tutorial exactly, I'm unsure what I've missed. I've certainly not seen many Service examples with constructors, and the reference code is auto-generated - so I don't want to go adding them manually to that.

Does anyone know of a solution/what I've done wrong? Thanks

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using TestOnline.ServiceReference1;

namespace TestOnline
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        DataService proxy;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            proxy = new DataService();
        }

        private void TestServiceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //call service and get response
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating an instance of the generated proxy client class.

It'll be named `DataServiceClient()` if it's been added correctly.

Comment: Oh. That simple. Thanks! Works perfectly. I can't mark as answer for 10 minutes, I think it's trying to point out how stupid I am.